# Integrability of absolute value of a compex function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose we have a bounded function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb C , [a,b] \subset \mathbb R$. The function is integrable if the integrals of the real and imaginary parts exist; in this case the integral of the function is defined as  $\int_{a}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{b} \mathcal Re (f) + i\int_{a}^{b} \mathcal Im (f)$.

There is a theorem saying that if $f$ is integrable, then $|f|$ also. I am not sure why it is so. Basically the theorem says that if $\mathcal Re f$ and $\mathcal Im f$ are integrable, then $\sqrt{\mathcal (Re f)^2 + \mathcal (Im f)^2}$ also. I do see why $\mathcal (Re f)^2 + \mathcal (Im f)^2$ is integrable, but can not see why the root of it also.

**EDIT**

I think I have figured this out.

As levap very helpfully pointed out if $f:[c,d] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $g:[a,b] \to [c,d]$ is integrable, then $f \circ g:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is integrable.

Proof: $f$ on $[c,d]$ is uniformly continuous and of course bounded. Take $\epsilon > 0$ and show that one can find $\psi, \phi:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ step functions such that $\psi \le f \circ g \le \phi$ on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b \phi - \psi < \epsilon$. From that the integrability of $f \circ g$ would follow.

It is possible to find $\delta' >0$, such that: $$\forall x_1, x_2 \in [a,b], |x_1 - x_2|< \delta' \implies |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|< \frac{\epsilon/2}{b-a}$$

Define $\delta :=\min\{\delta', \frac{\epsilon/2}{p-q} \}$ where $p := \sup_{[c,d]}f,q := \inf_{[c,d]}f$.

Because $g$ is integrable one can find $\phi',\psi'$ step functions on $[a,b]$ with $\psi' \le g \le \phi'$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_{i+1}-x_i)(M_i-m_i) < \delta^2$, where $M_i,m_i$ values of $\phi',\psi'$ on intervals $(x_i,x_{i+1})$.

$n$ intervals on which $\psi',\phi'$ are constant can be separated into two types: $A : = \{i\in \{1,\dots,n\}: M_i-m_i < \delta\}$, $B:=\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus A$.

It is clear that the total length of intervals "belonging" to $B$ is less than $\delta$. Otherwise $\sum_{i \in B} (x_{i+1}-x_i) \delta \le \sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_{i+1}-x_i)(M_i-m_i) < \delta^2$ would not be true.

Now we construct $\psi,\phi$: $$\psi = \inf_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}f \circ g \text{ on } (x_i,x_{i+1}), i \in \{1,\dots\,n\}$$ $$\phi = \sup_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}f \circ g \text{ on } (x_i,x_{i+1}), i \in \{1,\dots\,n\}$$

And finally:

$$\int_a^b \phi - \psi=\sum_{i=0}^n (x_{i+1}-x_i)(\sup_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}f \circ g - \inf_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}f \circ g) = \\ = \sum_{i \in A} (x_{i+1}-x_i)(\sup_{(x_i,x_{i+1})} f \circ g - \inf_{(x_i,x_{i+1})} f \circ g) + \sum_{i \in B} (x_{i+1}-x_i)(\sup_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}f \circ g - \inf_{(x_i,x_{i+1})}f \circ g) \\ \le \sum_{i \in A} (x_{i+1}-x_i)\frac{\epsilon/2}{b-a} + \sum_{i \in B} (x_{i+1}-x_i)(p-q) \\ \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \delta (p-q) \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon $$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume we are talking about the Riemann integral. In this case, one can prove that if $f$ is a continuous function and $g$ is integrable then $f \circ g$ is integrable (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions) for references). In particular, this implies that $(\operatorname{Re}(f))^2$ and $(\operatorname{Im}(f))^2$ are integrable and so is their sum and then also $\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(f)^2 + \operatorname{Im}(f)^2}$.

Comment: As you already have started dealing with me, could you please take a look at my edit above to check whether I have correctly got what you meant?